# Adobe SiteCatalyst - What does D mean in prop6=D=": "+pageName

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I see this often in Adobe SiteCatalyst (Reports and Analytics / Omniture / they've changed the name so many times)

```
prop6=D=": "+pageName
```

In the above s_code what does the 'D' do?

(It's difficult to find anything about the above behavior in a standard search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a dynamic variable. Here is some documentation from Adobe:

http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/trimming-the-fat-with-dynamic-variables/